# How to convert a string and call it as an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, jquery-plugins

I have the following plugin with few elements:

```
$.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

    // This is the easiest way to have default options.
    var settings = $.extend({
        amazon: "",
        download: "some text",
        purchase: "",
        apple: ""
    }, options );
};
```

And usually I call elements via `settings.item` such as `settings.amazon`. I just want to have a loop through the elements and check if they have value, if so `//do something`.
I wrote the below code:

```
let ds = ["download", "purchase", "amazon"]

$.each(ds, function (index, value) {
    console.log($(settings)[0] + value);
});
```

With the above code I want to check settings.download and show it's value. but `$(settings)[0] + value` does not get replaced with `settings.download` or `settings.amazon`. So it does not treat it as a call.

Any idea how I can loop through the elements based on the `ds` array and show the values of each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
let settings;

$.fn.greenify = function( options ) {
       // This is the easiest way to have default options.
       settings = $.extend({
        amazon: "",
       download: "some text",
        purchase: "",
        apple: ""
    }, options );
};

let ds = ["download", "purchase", "amazon"];

ds.forEach(value => {
    console.log(settings[value]);
});
```